# How to approve all installed apps permission programmatically in Django

Tags: python, django, django-permissions

`settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Local apps
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',

    # Third party apps
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]
```

`views.py`

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def create_group(request):
    groups = Group.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        group_name = request.POST.get('group_name')
        group = Group.objects.create(name=group_name)
        return HttpResponse(group.name)
    else:
        ctx = {'groups': groups}
        return render(request, 'users/admin/create_group.html', ctx)
```

**Here, I've created a view for creating user group programmatically. Now I want to allow users to approve permission just like django-admin dashboard. Like select few permissions and then press submit button to add these permissions to selected group.**
There must be some way doing so, because django admin itself doing it this way. I'd like to get some ideas how can I get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django implements this itself with a `ManyToManyField` between [**`Group`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#group-model) and [**`Permission`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Permission). The `Permission` object makes use of a `content_type` field to refer to the [**`ContentType`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model) that specifies all models.

If you thus want to add a permission with a given `codename` to a `Group`, you can use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

permission = Permission.odocumentenbjects.get(codename='add_mymodel')

mygroup.permissions.add(permission)
```

Or if you for example want to add all permissions for a given model *`Foo`*, you can use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

permissions = Permission.objects.filter(
    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Foo)
)

mygroup.permissions.add(*permissions)
```

You can also create extra permissions just like you create objects for another model and add these to group of course.

You can also add all permissions with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

permissions = Permission.objects.all()

mygroup.permissions.add(*permissions)
```

Comment: Hey, I really liked the approach. But I want to list all available permissions in the project (not individual models but all models in the project) and then add them into a group. How do I get all permissions of all installed apps?

Comment: @TareqMonwer: you use `Permission.objects.all()`.